# Why is session data lost using session_set_save_handler?

Tags: php, session, centos, php4, session-set-save-handler

I'm doing a migration of a PHP4 application from an old version of CentOS to a newer version.

I'm using session_set_save_handler and for some reason when the following callback is invoked,

> write(string $sessionId, string $data)

the $sessionId is set but the $data is empty.

My first guess would be the lack of the [WDDX](http://php.net/manual/fr/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler) module but i've already activated it and it appears correctly in the info.php page.

Do you think it might be a problem on the xml serialization ? 
Any idea of how to access an error message in some log file in order to find out the real cause?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the WDDX module was activated for some reason i ignore, php must actually be compile with this flag : `'--enable-wddx'`

> WDDX is only available, if PHP is compiled with WDDX support.

in

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.serialize-handler